# How does this assignment operation work..?

Tags: java, collections

I came across something new which i really found hard to understand.. Here is what i have done and it works perfectly fine..

```
    Vector<String[]> v = new Vector<String[]>();
    v.add(s);

    String[][] s1 = new String[v.size][]
    v.toArray(s1);
```

my question is how does it work even though method **toArray()** takes only 1-D array as argument..?
    I'm not much old for java programming so seeking an explanation..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are *only* really 1-D arrays in Java - where it *looks* like you've got a multi-dimensional array, it's actually just an array of arrays.

So if we ignore the fact that String[] itself is an array, and replace it with `StringArray` everywhere, we get this code:

```
Vector<StringArray> v = new Vector<StringArray>();
v.add(s);

StringArray[] s1 = new StringArray[v.size()];
v.toArray(s1);
```

Now that doesn't look so odd, right? `s1` is an array of string arrays, and `v` is a vector of string arrays. `v.toArray()` takes an array of string arrays as a parameter, so we can use `s1` as the argument.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple: `v` is a vector of 1-D arrays, `toArray` returns a 1-D array of whatever elements in the vector are (in this case 1-D arrays). The result is a 1-D array of 1-D arrays, more commonly known as a 2-D array.

Answer (score 1):

toArray() accepts a 1-D array of objects.

A string array is an object.

s1 is an array of string arrays.

QED

Answer (score 0):

The argument is treating "String[][]" as a "1-dimensional array" of the "String[]" objects.

In this case, Vector.toArray(T[] a) takes an array of T's. Let's replace the generic T with the type "String[]" (note that a String[] is an object). So this means Vector.toArray(String[][] a) takes String[][] as an argument.